# Python - input array has wrong dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimensions

I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to coding and recently I discovered talib.
I've been trying to calculate an RSI, but I encountered an error. I've been looking up the internet for a solution like I usually do, but without success. I'm guessing my data has a wrong datatype for the talib.RSI function, but that's about how far my knowledge goes.

Would be great if someone could come up with a solution and expand a little bit on it so I might be able to learn a bit along the way :-)

Many thanks in advance,

Mattie

```
import pandas as pd
import talib
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_excel (r'name.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['close'])

RSI_PERIOD = 14

close_prices = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['close'])
np_close_prices = np.array(close_prices)
print(np_close_prices)

rsi = talib.RSI(np_close_prices, RSI_PERIOD)
print(rsi)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 12 print(np_close_prices)
> 13
> ---> 14 rsi = talib.RSI(np_close_prices, RSI_PERIOD)
> 15 print(rsi)
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\talib_*init*_.py in wrapper(*args,
> **kwargs)
> 25
> 26             if index is None:
> ---> 27                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
> 28
> 29             # Use Series' float64 values if pandas, else use values as passed
>
> talib_func.pxi in talib._ta_lib.RSI()
>
> talib_func.pxi in talib._ta_lib.check_array()
>
> Exception: input array has wrong dimensions

Comment: A quick review of the Ta-Lib docs shows that the input (`np_close_prices`) should be `dtype=float64` and `shape=(#,)` (where # is the number of rows). `print(np_close_prices.dtype)` and `print(np_close_prices.shape)` to verify. I suspect the shape is incorrect. I am not familiar with Pandas, so can't diagnose the code the reads the XLSX file and converts to dataframes. If you can't debug, test with `close=np.random.random(100)`  ; `talib.RSI(close,14)` as shown in their docs.

Answer (score 0):

@kcw78 thanks for your reply.
I looked up the internet some more before I saw your reply and managed to find an answer. I have no clue what lambda is or what it does yet, but hopefully one day I'll find out and understand how this fixes the problem :)

```
import pandas as pd
import talib
import numpy as np

RSI_PERIOD = 14

data = pd.read_excel (r'name.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['close'])
rsi = df.apply(lambda x: talib.RSI(x, RSI_PERIOD))
rsi.columns = ['RSI']
print(rsi)
```